# Añadir efecto "transition" en Javascript para slider automatico

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un slider automático, no tengo el efecto que deseo en cada cambio de imagen

Quiero usar margen izquierdo de `n` píxeles en cada elemento y que al aplicar ese cambio haya una transición de `n` segundos, para que parezca que la imagen se va moviendo, pero no logro hacer que la transición me haga efecto. Estoy agregando la propiedad transition de forma dinámica por medio de **Javascript** para que cada elemento se anime de la forma que describí anteriormente.

```
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
       x[i].style.marginLeft = "500px";
       x[i].style.transition = "all 1s"


    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
<div class="container img-carrousel">

        <img class="mySlides" src="/img/Diablito.jpg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="/img/121.png">
        <img class="mySlides" src="/img/Diablito2.jpg">
        <img class="mySlides" src="/img/raspado1.jpg">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas agregando la transición justo después de agregar el cambio que quieres animar es decir, el elemento tiene una transición asignada luego de que aplicas tu margen.

Usar margenes para animar un elemento es una mala idea, ya que el navegador hace mas trabajo aplicando margenes que con otras propiedades que podrías seleccionar para esta tarea, como transform, que es la que uso en esta respuesta.

Si deseas hacer algo cuando termine la transición, agrega un controlador para el evento `transitionend`, cuando la transición termine osea cuando se termine de mover tu elemento podrías hacer algo como desaparecer el elemento, o agregarle otra clase a tu elemento para moverlo mas a la izquierda.

Organice mejor el código para lograr tu cometido primero ejecuto una funcion para agregar un escucha para el evento transitionend a cada elemento de tu lista.

`setTimeout` solo ejecutara la función una vez, si deseas ejecutar una funcion varias veces, usa `setInterval`

Hice una funcion para agregarla como argumento a `setInterval` esa funcion aplica la animacion a cada elemento de tu lista, el indice incrementa.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");

function transitionEnd(event){
  event.target.classList.add("img-carrousel__slideNoVisible")
}

function makeMovement(){
  if(myIndex+1 > slides.length){
    myIndex = 0
  }
  slides[myIndex].classList.add("img-carrousel__slideMovement")
  myIndex++;
}

function carousel() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].addEventListener("transitionend",transitionEnd)
    }
}

 carousel()
 setInterval(makeMovement, 2000);
```

```css
.container{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img-carrousel{
  position: relative;
}

.slide{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.slide:nth-child(1){
  background: orange;
}

.slide:nth-child(2){
  background: pink;
}

.slide:nth-child(3){
  background: lightgreen;
}

.slide:nth-child(4){
  background: brown;
}

.img-carrousel__slide--animatable{
  transition: all 1.5s;
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
 
}

.img-carrousel__slideMovement{
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}


.img-carrousel__slideNoVisible{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container img-carrousel">
        <img class="slide img-carrousel__slide--animatable" >
        <img class="slide img-carrousel__slide--animatable">
        <img class="slide img-carrousel__slide--animatable">
        <img class="slide img-carrousel__slide--animatable">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya pude arreglarlo, muchisimas gracias, el Interval sirve mas que setimeout para estos casos!